# Solidity unexpected response

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am getting `solidity unexpected response` while creating a solidity class and an interface with ethers.js for a voting blockchain

here is the solidity function

```
function addVoter(string memory _email) public returns (string memory) {
  return string('test');

  string memory key = random(_email);
  require(emailExists[key] == false);
  emailExists[key] = true;
  voters[key] = Voter({auth_code:key, authorized:true, candidate_id:0, email:_email, voted:false, voter_address:msg.sender});

  return key;
}
```

The function will create a new "Voter" structure and assign to it a random number.

To test the function a placed a return at the function`s start.

The return is supposed to be the system response.

So I expect to get something that will contain the `"test"` string.
Instead I get something like the following:

> {
>     hash: '0x2c9a61d3e903d706ca829d009d4fdd9f4c2972f17e7b0fb5e1c65b9a0f73436d',
>     blockHash: '0x690948bea16c079b1ba33a0c79aa76e987b828e92aebacc477ec6f6a9152416e',
>     blockNumber: 266,
>     transactionIndex: 0,
>     confirmations: 1,
>     from: '0x6002D48140d30B26C0B8A7B77D7Fa11A41a61a9F',
>     gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x4a817c800' },
>     gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5a53' },
>     to: '0xaa0E1b62f1de3fdEC6474FFb78714b18b5477e4b',
>     value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x0' },
>     nonce: 227,
>     data: '0xaca84892000000000000000000000000000000000000...',
>     r: '0xe9aef9a334b805240a4450845a640153292578b122ce487604ed3e4f135f70a3',
>     s: '0x0eddc482b19115e983018e4b9fe1541b325096ff61c581c559cc54f153527ae8',
>     v: 27,
>     creates: null,
>     raw: '0xf8ca81e38504a817c800825a5394aa0e1b62f...',
>     networkId: 0,
>     wait: [Function]
>   }

The above is the result of the following function build with ethers.js

```
contract.addVoter('some_email').then((par) => {
    registered = par;
    console.log(par);
});
```

The question is, did we do something wrong in our code or did we misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the smart contract, store that value in a variable and use `call` to get that value after the transaction is confirmed.
2. Use `event` to log the value

Comment: Ok, but how do I do this? the documentation got me all kinds of confused.

Comment: Ok, I found a way to implement the store and call method you proposed.

Comment: @GiwrgosGkogkas Hey! can you share how did you do it?